# Insert Formula into cell and extend down to last row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Anyone help me here i am receiving a Run-time error '1004'. Application-defined or object-defined error.

i am getting an error on line: lastrow = Sheets("CATAN").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(x1Up).Row

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("CATAN").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(x1Up).Row
Sheets("CATAN").Range("E:E").Locked = False
Sheets("CATAN").Range("E1").Select

ActiveCell.Formula = "=F1&""&G1"
Sheets(Catan).Range("E1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E1:E" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault

Sheets("CATAN").Range("E:E").Locked = True
```

The Data as it goes across Row 1 is

```
  A       |          B           |          C             |         D  |     E       |          F             |       G 100     |  492935.7   |     6898792     |     56.707    |               |        %PO         |  AB9265 101     |  492937.7    |     6898796     |     56.862    |   |          NS          |
```

So i cant work out were my error is.

Comment: Please [edit] your post. First, the title is meaningless. *VBA* and *Excel-VBA* are in the tags you used, so they aren't needed in the title. Removing them leaves *Code Error*, which conveys nothing. Your title should state the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that is descriptive enough to be useful when seen in a search result. Second, *my error* is useless as a problem description unless you tell us what the error is that you're getting. It's on the screen, right in front of you; there is absolutely no excuse for not sharing with us so we know what it is too.

Comment: it is not `x1Up`.  it is `xlUp` with a lower case `L` not a `1`.

Comment: made you adjustments however =F1&""&G1 works perfectly fine when i insert that formula into the cell myself. So before gifting me your great wisdom please check the formula and let me know if it works for you when typing it in.

Thank you Scott Craner

Comment: nope the formula will error, because it should be `"=F1&""""&G1"`

Comment: The string "=F1&""&G1" evaluates to `=F1&"&G1`, not to `=F1&""&G1`.

Comment: @ScottCraner - the `&""""&` won't actually achieve anything, will it?  I'm assuming in my answer that `=F1&G1` will achieve the same thing.  (Or is there some weird situation where concatenating a null string will allow something else to be cast to String?)

Comment: You also do need to unlock and lock the cells, just unprotect the sheet and you can make changes.

Comment: @YowE3K yes, I was just showing the OP how to insert double quotes through vba.

Comment: You can replace everything after the line that finds the last row with: `Sheets("CATAN").Range("E1:E" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1] & RC[2]"`

Comment: All working with Scotts Formula. Ty Again Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with 1 line of code:

```
Sheets("CATAN").Range("E1:E" & Sheets("CATAN").Range("F" & Rows.Count).end(xlup).row).formula = "=F1 & "" "" & G1"
```

Its smart enough to know you want to increment based on the row.

I assumed you wanted a space between the result of F1 and G1

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments:

It is lower case `L` instead of `1` in `xlUp`.

You do not need to unlock and relock the cells, only make sure the sheet is unprotected.

You can set the formula all at once with R1C1 notation.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("CATAN").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("CATAN").Range("E1:E" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1] & RC[2]"
```

Comment: You don't have to use R1C1 notation (See my answer below)

Comment: @DanDonoghue you are correct but I find it easier, myself to understand.  I also prefer to split long lines of code into variables, to me it makes it easier to read.  but thats my preference

Comment: It's funny, I hear so many people prefer it as they find it easier but I always found direct reference to be easier, horses for courses I guess :).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [the answer by Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755254/6535336) for a better way to implement your code, but I will leave the following here so you know what errors you had, so that you (and others) can avoid them in the future.

---

You have a typo - `x1Up` instead of `xlUp`.

You also have several other errors in your code, which are fixed below:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
'Fix typo and specify which sheet "Rows" refers to
lastrow = Sheets("CATAN").Cells(Sheets("CATAN").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("CATAN").Range("E:E").Locked = False
Sheets("CATAN").Range("E1").Select

'=F1&"&G1 is not a valid Excel formula 
ActiveCell.Formula = "=F1&G1"

'Variable Catan not defined - I assume you mean the string "CATAN"
Sheets("CATAN").Range("E1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E1:E" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault

Sheets("CATAN").Range("E:E").Locked = True
```